# Accidentally deleted disk, how to restore data?

Tags: hard-drive

While installing bootcamp I accidentally deleted (clean) the entire disk, now my entire data is gone. I saved it as it was in an image on an external disk. Disk utility won't mount the file and even when I mount it from command line, it won't repair the disk.

I used Testdisk and it's telling me that currently my partition looks like this:
[image]

when I run "deep search", it finds these two partitions:
[image]
Now how can I restore my data? How can I restore the correct partition table?

Photorec gives me this partition structure:
[image]

Comment: Macbook Pro Mid2012, disk is 750GB HDD. I don't understand why it shows those 2 partitions. I tried Photorec too and it displays a different partition structure. I updated the opening post. Can I not simply recreate a default partition table? It was a GUID partition table.

Comment: Why are you using this utility to recreate the partition table?

Comment: I tried to following this instructions but it won't work https://perrohunter.com/repair-a-mac-os-x-hfs-partition-table/

Comment: Are you just trying to rebuild the partition table or trying to recover your data?

Comment: I understood that in order to recover the data I need to rebuild the partition structure. The data should be still there. I didn't overwrite the data.

Comment: Use a tool like Disk Drill to recover your data.  You can rebuild your partition if you know the start and end sectors for each - do you have that info?

Comment: no that's why I was asking if there aren't default values for that

Comment: There's no default size for BC.  You pick the size - minimum is 64GB

Comment: drivesaver.com  give them a call for a price quote. maybe it would even be reasonable.

Comment: "Stellar Phoenix Macintosh - Mac data recovery software, recovers data from damaged, deleted, or corrupted volumes and even from initialized disks."
They have a trial version, so I guess you can see if your data can be recovered...
http://www.stellarinfo.com/mac-data-recovery.htm

Comment: FileSalvage is an extremely powerful Macintosh application for exploring and recovering deleted files from a drive or volume.  FileSalvage is designed to restore files that have:
-- been accidentally deleted.
-- become unreadable due to media faults.
-- been stored on a drive before it was re-initialized/formatted.